# Reactjs Async content render documentation

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, async-await

I! I'm doing a web page with reactjs and an api that gets data from a data base. In my homepage I want to display data from the database (for example: I have a number that keeps changing and I want to show it live on the homepage, so I want it to be shown on load, not on a button click).

I'm fairly new to react and i'm on a tight schedule to deliver this project, so if anyone knows any site or youtube video that could help me with this specific situation, I wouls help you a lot, since I found no info or what so ever online. (Maybe my searching skills are not on point)

Comment: The page load speed shouldn't matter, if you have an api call that returns something, and state to show the returned data, you'll see it after it fetches. Async/Await just doesn't let the scoped code proceed until it has a return value. Do you have a code snippet we could look at?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you should do is to create a state that will contain the data from database, and you need to fill the state when "componentDidMount" or "useEffect" if you are using react Hooks.

react documentation of componentDidMount:

[React componentDidMount](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidmount)

short example of what I meant:

```
import React, {useEffect, useState} from 'react'

const exampleApp = ()=>{
const [data,setData] = useState({})

useEffect(()=>{
   const data = await axios.get("yoururl");
   setData({...data})
},[])


return <div>{someMappingFunction(data)}</div>
}
```